# For Rails project, should we separate models into sub directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How should we separate models into sub directories? 100+ tables.

For example, for contract, there are

```
app/models/contract/contract.rb 
app/models/contract/contract_signer.rb

class Contract::Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
end
class Contract::ContractSigner < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

I dislike it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: are you sure you need that many tables?   what are some of the other table names you have?  there is no way to put similar records into the same table?

Comment: what you made works, so what is the problme ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to organize your models using directories, this is perfectly normal. You will need to add this directory to your load path in environment.rb.

The only thing that looks a little odd are your class names. Why don't you just use:

```
class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class ContractSigner < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Comment: config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/contract) into config/application.rb. model name is still looks good. Thank you.thank you

Answer (score 0):

We've got around 130 models here and are organizing them just as you said - except we're using `Contract::Base` from time to time. I recommend `Contract::Contract` and `Contract::Signer` here.

Comment: I think I once tried to do namespaced models and hit issues, but I don't remember. Are there any gotchas you have to deal with?

Comment: We use `class Contract::Base; abstract_base_class_with_table_prefix 'contract_`; end` and derive all classes in the namespace from that one.